# Create a table with a unique id and a set of distinct values in Contour

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I know how to do this with a data transformation. Now, suppose someone without a technical background needs to create a table with two columns:
id --> unique_id
vendor --> set of distinct values from a column that is included in the original dataset.

1st step : Remove all columns and keep only the Vendors column (done)
2nd step : Generate a list of distinct values. How can I do that?
3rd step : Add a unique id as a new column. Is that also possible?

I was able to perform the first action:
Remove all columns, only keep the Vendors column.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

1. Find unique values from a column
2. Create and assign a new unique value column

Let's solve them one by one.

1. There are multiple ways to achieve this in Contour. The one I would consider easiest for a less technical user is by using a pivot table. You can select the column you want to find unique values of (in your case vendor) in the `Rows` section of the pivot table configuration and select whatever you want in the Aggregates section (`Row count` works just fine). 
   Make sure to switch to pivoted data and your `vendor` column will have each of the values exactly once.
2. You already have unique ids from the previous step. You can use any injective function on values from the `vendor` column. 
   If you want to have them completely unrelated to the original values you can use the `Expression` board, create a new column and use `monotonically_increasing_id()` function to create new unique values. Bear in mind that these values will change when you change the input (If `VendorA` was mapped to `1` it doesn't mean it will be mapped to `1` next time you build the dataset).